# Sending ajax parameter to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a file drag and drop, and would like to use the same PHP page. I want to trigger the PHP script page using an action variable so it will go into the following if statement:

```
..
elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'uploadFile')
{
    TrackEvent('CHANNEL_ACTIVATE');

    echo "upload file";
}
```

I have an ajax call that is triggered using ondrop:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('action', 'uploadFile');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        try {
            var resp = JSON.parse(request.response);
        } catch (e){
            var resp = {
                status: 'error',
                data: 'Unknown error occurred: [' + request.responseText + ']'
            };
        }
        console.log(resp.status + ': ' + resp.data);
    }
};

request.open('POST', 'channelEdit.php');
request.send(data);

    $(this).unbind('click').click(function (e) {
    });


$( "#fileList" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: OK, so what is your problem

Comment: I want to send a parameter to trigger the if statement in the php script. At the moment this isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

while you are sending post data in ajax you have to add `setRequestHeader` in request

So change your script as below :

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('action', 'uploadFile');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'channelEdit.php');
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //<------Add this line

request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        try {
            var resp = JSON.parse(request.response);
        } catch (e){
            var resp = {
                status: 'error',
                data: 'Unknown error occurred: [' + request.responseText + ']'
            };
        }
        console.log(resp.status + ': ' + resp.data);
    }
};    

request.send(data);

    $(this).unbind('click').click(function (e) {
    });


$( "#fileList" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Comment: try edited code i have move `request.open()`  before `setRequestHeader`

Comment: that now works but it now shows error: Unknown error occurred: in the console

Comment: Its json parser error. You need to echo json data from php file

Comment: Ok, I'm confused on how to do this. I have the following in the PHP to try and solve this but its still throwing the error: echo json_encode($values);
    exit();